# Checking when a linear isomorphism is natural

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am thinking about what it means for linear maps to be "natural" and in particular I am thinking about the following example.  Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space with dimension $n$.  Then Hom$_{\mathbb{R}}(V\otimes\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R})\cong$ Hom$_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathbb{C}$ since they both have real dimension $2n$.  My question is whether or not there is a definition for this isomorphism that is independent of choice of basis and why.  It seems to me that this cannot be the case since we'd like to define the image of any $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $f$ on $V\otimes\mathbb{C}$ in Hom$_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathbb{C}$ as $f|_{V}\otimes \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is either $1$ or $i$, but how would you know which to choose?  How can I prove this more rigorously?

Edit: I am comfortable with the meaning of "natural" and "independent of choice of basis".  At this time I would just like to know whether or not such a natural isomorphism exists.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132254/discussion-on-question-by-sihoashoihd-checking-when-a-linear-isomorphism-is-natu).

Comment: @HarryGindi I lifted your chat suspension so you can continue this in the above link. Don't get in any trouble and make me look bad, please.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that a map is 'natural' is sometimes informally stated as being independent of choice of basis, but what it really means is that it's a component of a natural transformation between two functors.

Here, the functors are $\operatorname{Hom}(-\otimes \mathbb{C},\mathbb{R})$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathbb{C}$.  The question of whether they're naturally isomorphic requires you to produce a natural isomorphism between these two functors, which means a choice of isomorphism $$\alpha_V:\operatorname{Hom}(V\otimes \mathbb{C},\mathbb{R})\to\operatorname{Hom}(V,\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathbb{C}$$ for every choice of vector space $V$ such that for any map $f:W\to V$, you obtain a commutative square

$$\begin{matrix}&\alpha_W&\\\operatorname{Hom}(W\otimes \mathbb{C},\mathbb{R})&\cong&\operatorname{Hom}(W,\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathbb{C}\\\downarrow &&\downarrow\\\operatorname{Hom}(V\otimes \mathbb{C},\mathbb{R})&\cong&\operatorname{Hom}(V,\mathbb{R})\otimes \mathbb{C}\\&\alpha_V&
 \end{matrix}$$

These two functors may be naturally isomorphic, but, at least to me, not in an obvious way.

Comment: Naturality implies independence of choice of basis (consider any automorphism $f:V\to V$ (which precisely corresponds to a change of basis) in the naturality square), but it is strictly stronger than that. If you only require naturality with respect to isomorphisms, this is sometimes called 'canonicity' in the literature, but it is rare: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+transformation

Comment: how do you see that this implies independence of choice of basis?  I agree that I want to look at $f:V\rightarrow V$, but my brain gets stuck after that.  It is not clear to me why, if the horizontal maps are defined independent of basis, why the right one must necessarily map to the right thing.

Comment: The commutativity of the square in that case tells you that $\alpha_V \circ F(f) = G(f)\circ \alpha_V$, which is equivalent to saying that $G(f)^{-1} \circ \alpha_V \circ F(f) = \alpha_V$, so the natural transformation has to be invariant under change of basis. ($\alpha$ being a natural transformation between functors $F$ and $G$

Comment: Thank you, I think I see now.